# How to set html element position in percentages in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to set the position of a div to right 100% of the body. How-ever it needs to be done in JavaScript(or jQuery).

This is how i imagined the code would look...

```
const div = document.getElementById("div");
div.style.right = 100 + "%";
```

Any information or documentation for me to research would be greatly appreciated thank you. For clarification i want to move a div to the right side of the body, but i want to do it in percentages in javaScript.

Comment: Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: In new question edition - is it just `right: 0`?

Comment: @ vp_arth I cant believe i did not try that already. You did fix my issue Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) CSS property to set to 100%.

```js
const div = document.getElementById("div");
div.style.width = "100%";
```

```html
<div id="div" style="border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```

However, with the `div` tag, explicitly making its width 100% is unnecessary as it is a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) (having `display: block`) and will automatically inherit the width of its parent.

For a progress bar, you just need to set its width to `0%` at the start and gradually increase the `width` with a `setInterval`. Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.bar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
<p/>
<button onClick="run()">Start</button>
<script>
var bar = document.querySelector('.bar');
function run(){
var width = 0;
var intvl = setInterval(function(){
   width ++
   bar.style.width = width + "%";
   if(width>=100){
    clearInterval(intvl);
   }
}, 10);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am deleting this as i stated the question wrong. It makes no sense sorry lol

Comment: Without testing it, `div.style.width = "100%"` appears to be a minor simplification.

Comment: I edited my question im sorry if it is still unclear. I hope the edit makes more sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set `position:absolute` in this element and

Set `position:relative` in parent element

for css **position** property, percentage(%) works only for **absolute** position.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#child").css({
  "position":"absolute",
  "right":"0"
});

});
```

```css
#parent{
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   border:1px solid #000;
   height:100px;
}
#child{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A bit of explanation is appreciated in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> @vp_arth: In new question edition - is it just `right: 0`?
>   @kanna: I cant believe i did not try that already. You did fix my issue.

So, yes, `right` CSS property is a distance from right side.
Zero means «move a div to the right side of the parent»

[Answer Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51864782/revisions)